# Java swing jtextarea on a tab does not fill out the tab, cannot get it to fill even with scrollbar added

Tags: java, swing

So I'm using the Oracle tabbed example to create a Java swing application to help retrieve quick data from an internal database for a very small company and I'm very new at Java (decent scripting, though). My problem is that retrieved data from the database goes outside tab boundaries[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOZeG.png). From reading a question, I learned I should use a textarea, so I modified to use a text area but then I could not scroll. I fixed the scroll, but now the data is just in a small window on the tab. I can enlarge the tab, I have my scrolls, but I cannot fill out the text area.

This is the gridlayout from the documentation example:
`super(new GridLayout(8, 40));`

This is the pane that displays the information where inv is an array list defined as follows:
`ArrayList<String> inv = new ArrayList<String>();`

The data is pulled into the pane with the following code (note that the dimension does not change the text area, in fact, I do not believe this has any effect on the code at all so it is commented out during my testing:

```
    JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel(inv.toString());
    //panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    tabbedPane.addTab("Customers", null, panel2,
            "Displays Customer Details");
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        System.out.println(sqlException);
    }
```

This is the code for the panel using scroll tab, text area, etc. which is a modified version of the copied code:

```
    //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
    add(tabbedPane);
     
    //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
}
 
protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JTextArea filler = new JTextArea(text, 100, 50);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (filler, 
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    //filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextArea.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    //panel.add(filler);
    panel.add(scroll);
    return panel;
}
```

The tabbed pane is then displayed using the original code which I did not make any changes:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPane");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Add content to the window.
    frame.add(new TabbedPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
     
    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The question is, how can I get the text area to fill out the pane instead of just being 1/4 the size (regardless of how I resize the window either in the code or the GUI? The documentation doesn't seem to offer me much (based on searches) that work as I am already setting the scrollbar in the textarea like the documentation specifies. I tried setLineWrap(true) like another question but that was of no help either. See the image for an example of the issue I'm having. Any thoughts?

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);` is a bad idea

Comment: Use `panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` instead of `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));`

Comment: `inv.toString()` probably won't produce the results you're expecting.  You should be using a loop and maybe a `StringJoiner` to format the text the way you need it

Comment: So the reason I'm using the inv method is because I am pulling from an internal database so it comes like: String sql = "SELECT id, custname FROM customers WHERE account = 'active'"; and then pull it into a set of results - I'll look at the StringJoiner so thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `BorderLayout` to control the layout of the `JScrollPane` so it can automatically fill the available space.

You can control the `JTextArea`'s visible size via it's `rows` and `columns` properties

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Replace this with your text retrieval process
                List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>(128);
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/StarWarANewHope.txt")))) {
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.add(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                // Use this to format the results for the text area
                StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
                for (String line : text) {
                    joiner.add(line);
                }

                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Customers", null, new TestPane(joiner.toString()), "Displays customer details");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tabbedPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane(String text) {
            JTextArea filler = new JTextArea(text, 25, 25);
            filler.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            filler.setLineWrap(true);
            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(filler);
            //filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextArea.CENTER);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            //panel.add(filler);
            add(scroll);
        }
    }

}
```

If you continue to have issues, consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it takes out the guess work and generally results in better answers for more details

Comment: Perfect! Removing the scrollbar parts and switching to the border layout worked AND did it on all the tabs so I don't have to go through looking at this again. Very awesome, thank you so much!!